# How do to white list a specific IP with CSF?

Tags: csf, ftp

I am using csf & lfd, I am trying to allow all traffic to a specific IP (my backup storage) which I'm using lftp to access.

I have tried using `csf.allow`, but you have to specify a port or a range.
I've also tried adding the ip to `csf.ignore`

Neither of these approaches create any IPtables rules to allow traffic, adding a rule manually

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT` works fine but cleaned by csf on restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file /etc/csf/csfpre.sh and add your iptable rule.

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
```

chmod to created script csfpre.sh

```
chmod +x /etc/csf/csfpre.sh
```

CSF run csfpre.sh during startup.

Comment: superb, works perfectly, thanks and welcome to S.F